# Using Foreman's host groups in hiera.yaml :hierarchy section

Tags: puppet, foreman, hiera, satellite

Does anyone know how to set a correct path in :hierarchy section of hiera.yaml config to apply configuration to Foreman's host groups? I tried to use this settings with %{::hostgroup} variable, but it didn't work for me: https://github.com/aldavud/hiera-sat6/blob/master/docs/satellite6_hiera.md

Is this specific only to Satellite? Should I use different version(s) of Hiera/Puppet/Foreman? Any idea? :)

We are currently using Hiera 3.3.2, Puppet 4.10.9 and Foreman 1.15.6.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution...

At first I looked to puppetserver process with *strace*, and after running *puppet agent* on managed host I saw this in its output:

```
[pid  7997] stat("/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/hieradata/hostgroup/PROD/ubuntu/rabbitmq.yaml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121, ...}) = 0
[pid  7997] stat("/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/hieradata/hostgroup/PROD/ubuntu/rabbitmq.yaml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121, ...}) = 0
[pid  7997] stat("/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/hieradata/hostgroup/PROD/ubuntu/rabbitmq.yaml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121, ...}) = 0
[pid  7997] stat("/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/hieradata/hostgroup/PROD/ubuntu/rabbitmq.yaml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121, ...}) = 0
[pid  7997] stat("/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/hieradata/hostgroup/PROD/ubuntu/rabbitmq.yaml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121, ...}) = 0
[pid  7997] open("/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/hieradata/hostgroup/PROD/ubuntu/rabbitmq.yaml", O_RDONLY) = 37
```

Then we realized that rabbitmq.yaml is not well written, so after making some changes the host gets its configuration. And that's it.